# Как прописать правило, чтобы определенный элемент не отображался на определенной странице?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, виджет

На сайте Wordpress с Woocommerce установлен виджет, который в данный момент отображается и на странице каталога товара и на страницах с товаром (в категориях). Надо чтобы этот виджет отображался только на страницах с товаром (в категориях).
К примеру:
Класс виджета - .widget-4-site
1. Страница с каталогом - [http://мойсайт.ru/catalog](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/catalog)
2. Страница с товарами - [http://мойсайт.ru/catalog/название_категории](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/catalog/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)
Чтоб на 1 не было, а на 2 чтобы было.

Comment: Спасибо за скорость, но не сработало((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите убрать этот виджет через css, смотрите классы в body. Страница /shop стандартно имеет класс .archive. Из вопроса непонятно, то ли вы переименовали /shop, то ли у вас каталог на отдельной, обычной странице, выведен через шорткод. Обычные страницы в body имеют класс вида .page-id-321

Страница с товарами (страница категории) всегда имеет класс вида .term-7, где 7 - id категории товара.

Таким образом, убрать виджет через css на странице каталога можно так:

```
body .widget-4-site {
    display: none;
}

body.tax-product_cat .widget-4-site {
    display: block;
}
```

Правила должны следовать именно в таком порядке.

Comment: может у него не работает потому что нужно добавить display: none !important

Comment: @Даниил да у него такого правила нет в style.css

Comment: когда прописываю .archive .widget-4-site { display: none; } на всех страницах пропадает

Comment: Вот такая строка каталога `archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-product woocommerce woocommerce-page left-sidebar woocommerce-active storefront-top-bar-active responsive-menu-push-left`

Comment: А это строка категории `archive tax-product_cat term-plenka-agrostrejch term-28 woocommerce woocommerce-page left-sidebar woocommerce-active storefront-top-bar-active responsive-menu-push-left`

Comment: Теперь понятно, какие у вас классы. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: почему не работает данный вариант? отлично же походит ))  if(is_page(ID нужной странице)){} естественно ID нужно поменять на свое значение

Comment: Теперь все работает на ура! Спасибо!

Comment: @Даниил ваш вариант надо вставлять в код php, выводящий виджет. Если виджет стандартный, пользователь просто не будет знать, куда вставлять этот if. Более того, надо искать подходящий хук, чтобы не лезть в код темы storefront.